# Python: Rotate Block of Text

Tags: python, python-2.7

Let's say we have the following (but actually on a much larger scale):

```
ABCDEF
GHIJKL
MNOPQR
```

Is there a way to rotate it to read as the following:

```
FLR
DKQ
DJP
CIO
BHN
AGM
```

I wouldn't know where to start on account of it being Monday morning. Thanks,

JJ

Comment: How are you storing your inputs and outputs? Matrices, several arrays?
One option you have is creating matrices with the ASCII value of the characters and then use the transpose operator to obtain your desired output.

Comment: I'm currently looking at a text file - there's a laborious way I can think of (each line is exactly 75 characters long) but will look at what you suggested

Comment: Briefly: click the linked question, and scroll to the Python answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically just transforming the columns into the rows. This can be achieved with `zip()`:

```
lines = []
with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        lines.append(line.rstrip())

cols = zip(*lines)
for col in list(cols)[::-1]:
    print(''.join(col))
```

Outputs:

```
FLR
EKQ
DJP
CIO
BHN
AGM
```